# unable to set width of a reactjs popup

Tags: reactjs

I am using `reactjs-popup` and it displays its content. But I am unable to set its width. It is not taking effect for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried `width:'50%'` and `width:'50px'`. But it always displays the popup in a very wide huge rectangle. If I resize the whole browser only then the popup reduces in size.

```
<Popup  style={{width:'50%'}}
      open={true}
      closeOnDocumentClick
      keepTooltipInside=".tooltipBoundary"
    >
      <div className="modal" style={{display:'flex', background: 'radial-gradient(#cde6f9, #6191bf)'}}>
        <a className="close">
          &times;
        </a>
        <div style={{alignitems: 'center', justifycontent: 'center'}}>
        <h4>Enter Project Name : </h4>
        <input style={{alignitems: 'center', justifycontent: 'center'}} type="text" name="fname"></input><br/><br/>
        <button style={{alignitems: 'center', justifycontent: 'center'}} >Create</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </Popup>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the Popup component comes from an external package, try to read the documentation for more styling options.

You can probably also view the component in node_modules/[package_name] folder. Try giving it a className there or style it using the style property.

Finally, you can try wrapping the popup with another element and capture the style using css.
Something like that:

```
.popup-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
.popup-wrapper > * {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that you can view the elements with the inspector and check if they have class attributes. If they do you might be able to style them directly using css.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly globally update the content styles as other posts here imply. But if you want to set the style for a specific popup...

If you inspect the `<Popup` HTML, you will see there are two `divs`. One has a class defined with `popup-content` and a second named `popup-overlay`. You can overwrite the styles here using the `contentStyle` and `overlayStyle` attributes of any given `<Popup`.

For example if you want to change the width of the content:

```
<Popup
    ...set other attributes here as needed
    contentStyle={{ width: '100%' }}
>
    Show this content
</Popup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the popup in div and give it a class like modalWrapper. 
You can target the main popup container div by using this css.

```
.modalWrapper > div > div  {
    width: 484px !important;
    padding: 24px !important;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```